# establishing a session with jquery

Tags: jquery, session, cookies, browser

I'm not sure if this issue would be handled by the browser, but here is the scenario:

I have a RESTful server, where if a client sends a GET request to `/login-verify?id_token=XXXX`, then the server would respond back with either

- an error code
- or a 200 OK message, *with* a `Set-Cookie` session cookie header.

My question is this: would *further* requests send the cookie I just set, if the requests were made with jQuery's `$.ajax`? Or would they be included with *any* request (until I manually cleared the cookies from the browser)?

Comment: Once a HTTP response gets a `Set-Cookie` on all further requests the cookie will be sent along with.

Comment: Thank you @KishoreSahas, this is exactly what I was wondering. Feel free to make an answer to claim it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Once a HTTP response gets a `Set-Cookie` on all further requests the cookie will be sent along with.

For more information, please see : https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/05/http-cookies-explained